# How to get user payment details in iTunes on developer side?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I have recently submitted  my app in Appstore with in-app-purchase  feature,
it is work fine in live server but, some customer pay the payment in my IOS app not updated his profile in my server database,
Can i get User Payment details in my iTunes account on developer side for checking payment based on orderID.
If it is possible where i can get details in iTunes account  or any other possibility.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get any sales related data for us developers, like Apple ID, form of payment, Credit Card details etc.

Please clarify, what you want to do exactly.

The only thing you can do it "Receipt Validation", from within the app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html